# yield is not working in partials other than application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here I have a requirement to use yield in a partial other than application.html.erb , when I try this in partial it was showing me the blank value and if I try the yield in application.html.erb it was showing the value.

application.html.erb

```
body>
<div id="main-container">
  <%= content_for?(:page_header) ? yield(:page_header) : (render :partial => "/shared/home_header") %>
  <div id="middle-container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom-container">
    <%= render "/shared/bottom_partial" %>
  </div>
```

index.html.erb

```
<% content_for :page_header do %>
  <%= render :partial => "/shared/employer_header" %>
<% end %>
<% content_for :page_name do %>
  <p>My Account</p>
<% end %>
<div>
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
</div>
```

/shared/_employer_header.html.erb

```
 <div class="heading" >
    <%= yield(:page_name) %>
 </div>
```

When I am trying like above I am getting blank value in yield :page_name in  employer header if I try the yield :page name in application.html.erb I am getting the value.Can any one help me to sort this out.Thank'U'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the order of your two content_fors so the :page_name is defined before the partial is rendered.

index.html.erb

```
<% content_for :page_name do %>
  <p>My Account</p>
<% end %>
<% content_for :page_header do %>
  <%= render :partial => "/shared/employer_header" %>
<% end %>
```